# How can I disable the register route using Laravel version 8.83.4?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-8, laravel-fortify

How can I disable the 'register' route using Laravel version 8.83.4

---- This does not work

```
Auth::routes([
    'register' => false
]);
```

Apparently, I am supposed to use fortify but there is no fortify in the config directory

----- This is not there

config/fortify.php

```
'features' => [
    // Features::registration(), // disable here
     Features::resetPasswords(),
     Features::emailVerification(),
     Features::updateProfileInformation(),
     Features::updatePasswords(),
     Features::twoFactorAuthentication(),
],
```

---

Comment: Publish fortify config

Answer (score 0):

What if you create routes yourself:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('login',  'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```